# return data from a function called by tkinter button

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter

I need to return data from a function that is called by a tkinter button.

```
root= Tk()
def random():
    num_1= random.randint(0,12)
    num_2= random.randint(0,3)
    return num_1,num_2

num_1= None
num_2= None
Play=ttk.Button(text="Play",command=random)
Play.grid(row=3,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Im not sure where the return actual stored the variables because when i print num_1 and num_2 both print None instead of the expected random numbers.
Any input will be appreciated.

(also i have a mainloop etc.)

Comment: reading this back i realise the code doesnt make much sense, but that is sort of the problem. i dont actually know how to do this (the title).

Comment: You want to return values. Return them _where_? Buttons can’t return values to anywhere.

Comment: It is hard to explain what i wanted to ask because the actual code is 100 lines long, however i figured it out by calling another function, called returN(), with the button which then called random() and returned num_1 and num_2 to returN()

Answer (score 1):

if you meant to declare `num_1` and `num_2` as global variable then you should declare it in random function.

```
root= Tk()
def random():
    global num_1, num_2
    num_1= random.randint(0,12)
    num_2= random.randint(0,3)
    return num_1,num_2

num_1= None
num_2= None
Play=ttk.Button(text="Play",command=random)
Play.grid(row=3,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

do what you want the function to do inside the function in this scenario.

```
from tkinter import  *

import random

root= Tk()
def random_():
    num_1= random.randint(0,12)
    num_2= random.randint(0,3)
    # return num_1,num_2
    print(num_1,num_2)

num_1= None
num_2= None
Play= Button(text="Play",command=random_)
Play.grid(row=3,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

return

would work if you do

```
print(random_)
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefer do not use global variables

```
from tkinter import *
import random


def random_(tmp_list):
    tmp_list[0] = random.randint(0, 12)
    tmp_list[1] = random.randint(0, 3)


root = Tk()
tmp_list = [None, None]
Play=Button(text='Play', command=lambda: random_(tmp_list))
Play.grid(row=3, column=0)
root.mainloop()

print(tmp_list[0], tmp_list[1])
```

Comment: it is an interesting idea using lambda functions to do such a thing. although it suits javascript better.

Comment: imho, avoid using global variables is more interesting idea)

Comment: The globals `num_1` and `num_2` will not be affected by the function `random(num_1, num_2)`.  Try to print the values of `num_1` and `num_2` after `root.mainloop()`.  You will get `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably has a mistake as it seems you import `random module` and called your callback function `random` too.

Another cause for the issue here is that you affect local variables instead of global ones.